# How to update an image without adding new colorbar every time

Tags: matplotlib

I am displaying an image with `matplotlib`. However, every time I update this image, a new `colorbar` is added to the right and my image is shrunk.

1st time running the code
[image: First time]

2nd time running the code
[image: Second time]

3rd time running the code
[image: Third time]

4th time running the code
[image: Fourth time]

if `slice1` is a 2D array

```
plt.figure("slice 1")
plt.imshow(slice1)
plt.colorbar()
plt.clim(0, 1000)
plt.set_cmap('gray')
plt.show()
```

I would like to have the colorbar and image stay at the same place every time I run these lines.

Comment: What code are you using to 'update' the image?

Comment: You are adding a new image each time as well so you have four images laid on top of each other.  Do this for too long and you will run out of memory. Easiest is just to close the figure each time or open a new one   If you don’t want to do that you can update the data in the image.

Comment: @AriCooper-Davis, I simply run the code again to 'update' it